# Creating permuations of JSON object?

Tags: javascript, python, json, recursion

If I'm given an input like this:

```
[
    {
        "name":     "Robert",
        "city": "New York",
        "short":  "Bob"
    },
    {
        "name":     "Allison",
        "city": "Los Angeles",
        "short":  "Ally"
    },
    {
        "name":     "James",
        "city": "Chicago",
        "short":  "Jim"
    },
    {
        "name": "Hannah",
        "city":"Toronto",
    },
    {
        "name": "Elizabeth",
        "city": "London",
    }
]
```

How would I go about producing an output such as this, where I get all possible combinations?

```
[
    {"Robert": "New York", "Allison": "Los Angeles", "James": "Chicago", "Hannah": "Toronto", "Elizabeth": "London"},
    {"Bob": "New York", "Allison": "Los Angeles", "James": "Chicago", "Hannah": "Toronto", "Elizabeth": "London"},
    {"Robert": "New York", "Ally": "Los Angeles", "James": "Chicago", "Hannah": "Toronto", "Elizabeth": "London"},
    {"Bob": "New York", "Ally": "Los Angeles", "James": "Chicago", "Hannah": "Toronto", "Elizabeth": "London"},
    {"Robert": "New York", "Allison": "Los Angeles", "Jim": "Chicago", "Hannah": "Toronto", "Elizabeth": "London"},
    {"Bob": "New York", "Allison": "Los Angeles", "Jim": "Chicago", "Hannah": "Toronto", "Elizabeth": "London"},
    {"Robert": "New York", "Ally": "Los Angeles", "Jim": "Chicago", "Hannah": "Toronto", "Elizabeth": "London"},
    {"Bob": "New York", "Ally": "Los Angeles", "Jim": "Chicago", "Hannah": "Toronto", "Elizabeth": "London"},
]
```

StackOverflow family please help.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to generate such permutations yourself yet? Also note that your desired output is invalid, strings need to be enclosed in delimiters like `'` and `"`

Comment: All possible combinations of _what_? What's the rule there? If you can explain it in English, it should be pretty easy to turn into code, but if you can't, it's impossible to do (except by a lucky guess).

Comment: The input also isn't valid, either as JSON or as a Python literal, for the same reason.

Comment: Im trying to produce all combinations of the names of each person. Each person has either two types of names. One is just the "name" the other is a "short" name.  While also outputting the names, I want to output the city along with the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to take the cartesian product, not the combinations, of each possible name-city pair you can get for each person. that is, the cartesian product of these lists:

```
[('Robert', 'New York'), ('Bob', 'New York')]
[('Allison', 'Los Angeles'), ('Ally', 'Los Angeles')]
[('James', 'Chicago'), ('Jim', 'Chicago')]
[('Hannah', 'Toronto')]
[('Elizabeth', 'London')]
```

---

The first thing you need is a function that turns a person name-city-short dict into a list of name-city/short-city pairs:

```
def pairs(person):
    names = [(person['name'], person['city'])]
    try:
        names.append((person['short'], person['city']))
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return names
```

Now, you need to apply this to everyone with `map` or a comprehension:

```
allpairs = map(pairs, people)
```

Now you have something you can just call product on:

```
results = itertools.product(*allpairs)
```

And now you just have to turn each list of pairs into a dict:

```
output = [dict(result) for result in results]
```

And then you have to write the code to put them in the strange order you wanted (maybe you just want to product them in reverse and then reverse it?), and to output it in that format that looks a little bit like a Python dict repr or a JSON object but isn't actually either. (Also, if the order of each dict is important, and you're not using Python 3.7 or later, you'll need to use `collections.OrderedDict` instead of `dict`.)

Comment: thanks! ill try this out. output order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an only-[jq](/questions/tagged/jq) solution that, indeed, uses the built-in function, `combinations`.  It does, however, assume that the input is valid JSON.

```
[ map([ {(.name):.city},
        (if .short then {(.short):.city} else empty end) ] )
  | combinations
  | add ]
```

### Output

```
[
  {
    "Robert": "New York",
    "Allison": "Los Angeles",
    "James": "Chicago",
    "Hannah": "Toronto",
    "Elizabeth": "London"
  },
  {
    "Robert": "New York",
    "Allison": "Los Angeles",
    "Jim": "Chicago",
    "Hannah": "Toronto",
    "Elizabeth": "London"
  },
  {
    "Robert": "New York",
    "Ally": "Los Angeles",
    "James": "Chicago",
    "Hannah": "Toronto",
    "Elizabeth": "London"
  },
  {
    "Robert": "New York",
    "Ally": "Los Angeles",
    "Jim": "Chicago",
    "Hannah": "Toronto",
    "Elizabeth": "London"
  },
  {
    "Bob": "New York",
    "Allison": "Los Angeles",
    "James": "Chicago",
    "Hannah": "Toronto",
    "Elizabeth": "London"
  },
  {
    "Bob": "New York",
    "Allison": "Los Angeles",
    "Jim": "Chicago",
    "Hannah": "Toronto",
    "Elizabeth": "London"
  },
  {
    "Bob": "New York",
    "Ally": "Los Angeles",
    "James": "Chicago",
    "Hannah": "Toronto",
    "Elizabeth": "London"
  },
  {
    "Bob": "New York",
    "Ally": "Los Angeles",
    "Jim": "Chicago",
    "Hannah": "Toronto",
    "Elizabeth": "London"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a Javascript solution, you'd need your own Cartesian product function, but the rest is fairly similar to the Python solution above.  This one uses a variadic Cartesian function I had around, so requires the extra step of `cartesian.apply(null, arr)`.  But other than that, it should be straightforward:

```js
const cartesian = (xs, ys, ...zs) => ys 
  ? cartesian([].concat(...xs.map(x => ys.map(y => [].concat(x, y)))), ...zs) 
  : xs;

const toObj = xs => xs.reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(a, b), {})

const toNames = people => people.map(person => Object.keys(person)
  .filter(name => ['name', 'short'].includes(name))
  .map(name => ({[person[name]]: person.city}))
)

const nameCombos = people => cartesian.apply(null, toNames(people)).map(toObj)

const people = [
    { name: "Robert",    city: "New York",    short: "Bob"  },
    { name: "Allison",   city: "Los Angeles", short: "Ally" },
    { name: "James",     city: "Chicago",     short: "Jim"  },
    { name: "Hannah",    city:"Toronto"                     },
    { name: "Elizabeth", city: "London"                     }
]

console.log(nameCombos(people))
```